# Method defined in Rails 3.2.12 engine not found in proudction while available in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a method load_session_variable defined in rails engine authentify and being called by controllers in other rails engine. In development, there is no problem finding the method. However in production, there is an error:

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://6.95.25.93/nbhy/projectx/misc_definitions/new.js?for_which=project_status&subaction=project_status"
```

In production.log, the error is:

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `load_session_variable' for #<Projectx::MiscDefinitionsController:0x0000000456f7f8>):
```

The method is defined in engine authentify as:

```
   def load_session_variable
      session[:for_which] = @for_which if @for_which.present?
      session[:which_table] = @which_table if @which_table.present?
      session[:subaction] = params[:subaction] if params[:subaction].present?
    end

    module_function :load_session_variable
```

The module_function declaration is supposed to make the method available for others. The production environment is ubuntu 12.04 with nginx/passenger. The development is in Windows. How to fix the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you didn't restart nginx in production after updating your code base.

e.g.

```
  $ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```